# How to make Webkit uses google chrome flash player?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using webkit in my vb.net application. my application bascially open videos from youtube and other sites. Google chrome has built-in flash player. my questions are:
WebKit uses google chrome to diplay the webpage or it uses a seperate browser to do so?
If i want to open the video in google chrome browser how can i do that in my vb.net application?

Answer (score 1):

No, WebKit does not use Google Chrome to display web content (it is a separate engine), and thus it cannot use Chrome's built-in Flash Player.

(At the risk of confusion I'll explain that, technically, [Chrome has some of WebKit embedded in it](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/webmasters-faq.html). But to be clear: your use of WebKit in VB.Net does not share any components with Chrome's version.)

Alas, [lots of people have attempted to embed a Chrome browser in a .NET control, and so far it seems none of them work well](http://www.whattofix.com/blog/archives/2010/09/google-chrome-a.php).